Can't assign value to variable inside loop based on color description in swiftui
I have an fixed array of allowed colors as "availableColors"
I have a "thisColor" color variable used to fill a rectangle (predefined as "Color(.blue)" in the code below)
I also have a string variable "colorString" ("pink" in the code below)
If "colorString" matches the Color.description of any item in "availableColors", variable "thisColor" should be assigned that item.
I must be missing something because while I can loop through the colors, I can't assign the variable color.
The code and preview are below. If the commented line is uncommented, the preview fails with the generic message: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report
I am sure I am missing something obvious, since this doesn't seem to be too weird. But I can't figure out what.
Note: The end goal is to assign the color of a view based on a saved string from reading a file. This saved string would be used to look up the corresponding color and that color would be applied. The code below is a simplification to show how the assignation fails. The end goal is not to build a list but to apply the correct color to a view based on a string. The code shows the contents of the array only as reference.
import SwiftUI

struct testView: View {
    
    let availableColors: [Color] = [.blue,.pink,.gray]
    
    @State private var thisColor = Color(.blue)
    var colorString = ".pink"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text(thisColor.description)
                .bold()
            Divider()
            ForEach(availableColors, id: \.self) { colorItem in
                Text(colorItem.description)

                if(colorItem.description == colorString) {
                    // thisColor = colorItem
                }
            }
            Rectangle()
                .fill(thisColor)
                .frame(width:50,height:50)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    testView()
}

(I'm not sure how to best summarize the question. I'll edit with suggestions to best do so)

Why do you need to have a second string property, can’t you use only the Color property? Depending on what your goal is here maybe List(selection:) could work, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list

thisColor = colorItem is supposed to return a View. You cannot run code which assigns something  in the rendering area of a SwiftUI view. If you could you would run into an infinite loop in this case. By the way be aware that the description of a SwiftUI color doesn't have a leading dot.

@JoakimDanielson The end goal is to have that color coming from values saved to disk as json. That variable would eventually be replaced by looking up the saved value. The code presented is a simplified version of the code, without all extraneous stuff.

@vadian Thanks. I know about the dot. I pasted an example with it but had tried both ways. Nonetheless, at worst it wouldn't match and leave the default value but the line was failing altogether.
I don't think I have internalized that Color is a View. You mean I can't reassign "thisColor" then? How could I do this then?

The if expression makes not sense at all anyway. Better use a selection as suggested by Joakim or apply the onChange modifier monitoring colorString.

@vadian I understand and in the end solution I may not use an "if" statement, but the problem I have is I can't work out how to assign the color based on a string matching predefined values. In this example the string is the same as the color name, but that's not a requirement.
I may just be tilted and missing the obvious response, though. My rubber duck today hasn't been much help.

If you need to do this assignment when the view is first shown, then you can use the .onAppear modifier where you can write normal swift code in the closure to check and use your string property. If you on the other hand needs to check/update the property when a selection is changed see the previous comments about selection and onChange

@JoakimDanielson I was overcomplicating myself enormously because I was approaching the issue in a way that may not be easy to solve today and that led me through a weird path.
My goal was to be able to call colors by their names, if their name matched an existing string.
In the end I made a switch statement with the colors of the system. In the future I would still want to call colors by name as a string since I don't want to have to modify this list if Apple adds more named colors. But today it works, thanks!

As assumed, I was overcomplicating my own life based on bad practices inherited from other languages and lack of caffeine.
I needed to map a color to a string, so I could just use a mapping table. I would prefer to skip the mapping table and be able to call colors by name but this will do in the meantime.
Thanks everyone for your patience.
import SwiftUI

struct testView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        let colorString = "red"
        let thisColor = Color(colorName: colorString)
        Rectangle()
                .fill(thisColor ?? .clear)
                .frame(width:50,height:50)
    }
}

extension Color {
    
    init?(colorName: String) {
        switch colorName {
        case "orange":     self = .orange
        case "red":        self = .red
        case "yellow":     self = .yellow
        case "green":      self = .green
        case "mint":       self = .mint
        case "teal":       self = .teal
        case "cyan":       self = .cyan
        case "blue":       self = .blue
        case "indigo":     self = .indigo
        case "purple":     self = .purple
        case "pink":       self = .pink
        case "brown":      self = .brown
        case "gray":       self = .gray
        case "primary":    self = .primary
        case "secondary":  self = .secondary
        case "clear":      self = .clear
        default:           return nil
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    testView()
}

